# Html Canvas/jquery : Animation when changing the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm looking to make a kind of 'slide' animation effect when changing my canvas,

Right now i'm outputing my image with:

```
ctx2.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0)
```

imgData being my processed image data,

what i am looking to do is have a nice slide effect or at least understand how to add transition effects to it instead of just having the image change.

Comment: The canvas is like an empty piece of paper where you can draw upon. So if you want to change something, you've got 2 options: Add more to what's already there or erase it and draw something new. So for animation effects, you simply erase and reposition with coordinates in a loop. Something like `while(true){ x = x-1; if(x < 0){ break; }`.

Comment: Obviously that's a basic example that wouldn't give good results. You'll have to use a timer for more smooth effects. Otherwise it'll be based on the CPU which goes so fast that a human eye can't even see the animation.

Comment: Ok, thank for your response i was trying to mess around with moving the image with the x, as you say it's not very smooth oir it gets lagging. Do you have an exemple of using a timer ?

Comment: `var myTimer = setInterval(function(){ x = x-1; }, 25);` This will cause `myTimer` to loop every 25 miliseconds. Once it's finished, kill it with `clearInterval(myTimer);`. So add an if condition for x where you kill it.

Comment: You're the mvp, that works perfect, thanks. :)